# Div over image and mouseover event

Tags: jquery, css, hover

I have a site with images and some of them have a "play" (a div positioned absolutely and managed via click event on jQuery) over it.

In some images I must to change the opacity when the mouse is over the image.

When an imagen have at same time the "play" and the opacity change, this is happening (place the mouse over the "play" div): http://jsfiddle.net/S53b5/

I have tried different solutions only CSS or using jQuery, but anything works :(

Thanks!

Comment: As some comments have suggested, I have tried to change the opacity via mouseover event, but when I place the mouse over the play the opacity still is blinking. Test: http://jsfiddle.net/S53b5/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this [demo](http://jsbin.com/uxubut/1/edit)

```
   $("img").mouseout(function(){
     $(".play").css("opacity","1")
    }).mouseover(function(){
     $(".play").css("opacity",".5");
    });
```

Updated [Demo2](http://jsbin.com/uxubut/6/edit)

```
$("img").mouseout(function(){
        $(".play").css("opacity","1");
         $(this).css("opacity",".1");
    }).mouseover(function(){
        $(".play").css("opacity",".5");
        $(this).css("opacity","1");
    });

$(".play").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).css("opacity","1");
        $("img").css("opacity","1");
    });
```

Comment: I'm trying it but when I place the mouse over the div, the problem is still there, the opacity is blinking.

Comment: check the updated demo and let me know if this is what you want?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("img").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).css("opacity",".8");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#(yourimageid)").mouseover(function(){
$(this).css("opacity","0.7")
})
```